Trimble Pro XT SSF Correction
I am using a Trimble Pro XT GPS and am having trouble differentially correcting the .ssf files.  This is a new problem - differential corrections have been working fine until the beginning of this year.  I updated the firmware about 3 years ago.
Depending on the CORS that I use, I get errors ranging from "Unable to transfer files..." to "Failed to correct 225 positions."
When I process data collected by a Trimble R2 during the same time period as the Pro XT, I have no problem.
Does anybody have any ideas on how to get this process to work properly?

From the Base Provider Search choose the Select button.
Choose the Update List to refresh the provider.  Try again.

This worked up to a year or so for me but not anymore (but I suspect a firewall issue with my organization).  Now I need to download rinex files and correct against the downloaded file.  In WA State you can guest log into WRSN as user guest and password guest to get a correction file.  Maybe you have a similar provider in your area.

Refer to this Support Note from Trimble
Some legacy Trimble GNSS receivers (ProXT, ProXH, GeoExplorer 2008, GeoExplorer 3000) stopped calculating the date correctly on August 20, 2023.  These receivers will still determine the position correctly in real time but post-processing will not work.
The symptoms you see when you try to post-process are probably because the post-processing software is asking the base station / reference network for Rinex data for some time in year 2004.  Most base stations / networks will not still have this, but even if they can provide data, GPS Base data from 2004 will not match the GPS Measurement data for 2024 so post-processing will fail.
